# How to read in special keys with Win32::Console?

Tags: perl, terminal

When I press the `Up`-key, this script ([Term::TermKey](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term%3a%3aTermKey)) outputs `You pressed: <Up>` .

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use Term::TermKey;

my $tk = Term::TermKey->new( \*STDIN );
say "Press any key";
$tk->waitkey( my $key );
say "You pressed: <" . $tk->format_key( $key, 0 ) . ">";
```

How could I reach the same result with [Win32::Console](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aConsole)?
I tried this, but it worked only on "normal" keys like `l`,`k`, ... but not with keys like `Up`, `Delete`, ...

```
use Win32::Console;

my $in = Win32::Console->new(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
$in->Mode(ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT);
my $result = $in->InputChar(1);
say "<$result>";
```

How could I make work keys like `Up`, `Delete`, ... too with `Win32::Console`?

Comment: "Up" is not a character. I imagine you would have to use `Input`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The up key does not result in a character. `InputChar` cannot possible return it. You need to use `Input`.

```
my $con_in = Win32::Console->new(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
for (;;) {
   my @event = $con_in->Input();

   my $event_type = shift(@event);
   next if !defined($event_type) || $event_type != 1;  # 1: Keyboard

   my ($key_down, $repeat_count, $vkcode, $vscode, $char, $ctrl_key_state) = @event;
   if ($vkcode == VK_UP && ($ctrl_key_state & SHIFTED_MASK) == 0) {
      if ($key_down) {
         say "<Up> pressed/held down" for 1..$repeat_count;
      } else {
         say "<Up> released";
      }
   }
}
```

See [KEY_EVENT_RECORD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684166%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information about keyboard events.

See [Virtual-Key Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to identify keys.

---

Headers and definitions for above code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use Win32::Console qw( STD_INPUT_HANDLE );

use constant {
   RIGHT_ALT_PRESSED  => 0x0001,
   LEFT_ALT_PRESSED   => 0x0002,
   RIGHT_CTRL_PRESSED => 0x0004,
   LEFT_CTRL_PRESSED  => 0x0008,
   SHIFT_PRESSED      => 0x0010,

   VK_UP => 0x26,
};

use constant SHIFTED_MASK =>
   RIGHT_ALT_PRESSED |
   LEFT_ALT_PRESSED |
   RIGHT_CTRL_PRESSED |
   LEFT_CTRL_PRESSED |
   SHIFT_PRESSED;
```