# Term::ReadKey::ReadKey: Why MS Windows behaves differently than Linux?

Tags: perl, keyboard, terminal

[Term::ReadKey](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term%3a%3aReadKey):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use Term::ReadKey;

my $key;

ReadMode 4;
print "Enter a key: ";
$key = ReadKey();
printf "|%s|\n", $key // 'undef';
$key = ReadKey(-1);
printf "|%s|\n", $key // 'undef';
$key = ReadKey(-1);
printf "|%s|\n", $key // 'undef';
ReadMode 0;

say "END";
```

When I run this script on Windows or Linux an press `k` I get both times this output:

```
Enter a key: |k|  
|undef|  
|undef|  
END
```

When I press the `Up` "key" I get

```
Enter a key: |  
|[|  
|A<  
END
```

on Linux, but on Windows the script comes to standstill:

```
Enter a key:
```

Why do I get here not some strange signs instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, Term::ReadKey assumes Unixy terminals, which Windows doesn't provide (unless you use Cygwin).

You might try [Win32::Console](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-Console-0.09/Console.pm) instead. Or there may be some incantations that will get Term::ReadKey to work--good luck on that.

Comment: The documentation sounds more optimistic: `One of the main goals is to have the functions as portable as possible, so you can just plug in "use Term::ReadKey" on any architecture and have a good likelyhood of it working.`

Answer (score 1):

You can't get keys from an interface that give you characters. That's why you got a whole bunch of stuff for one key.

On the unix side, the keys got transformed into terminal-specific inline escape sequences you have to figure out yourself.

In Windows, you can get the keys themselves, but obviously not from a interface that gives you characters like `ReadKey` apparently does.

I recently [showed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172253/how-to-read-in-special-keys-with-win32console) how to get keys in Windows. No idea how to do so in unix.